# undefined method `valid?' for 2:Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm follow [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?view=comments) to try and upload an xls file with validation in rails, but am getting the following error:

> undefined method `valid?' for 2:Integer

This is my code:

```
def save
  if imported_products.map(&:valid?).all?
    imported_products.each(&:save!)
    true
  else
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should work. How does your `imported_products` look?

Comment: As your error is telling you it looks like `imported_products` is an array of integers or one of them is an integer. `.valid?` is used for checking errors on objects. [Read more](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Validations/valid%3F)

Comment: @PeterHøjlundAndersen thanks it worked for me

Comment: Can you give me a helping flag then?